"Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}" in subfile when compiling in TeXstudio
"Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}" is printed when I compile a subfile in TeXstudio. (I.e., when I hit F5 when in the subfile. F7 does not work either.)
In one special case, in the preamble of the main file, I had \input standard_settings.tex. That file contained \begin{document}. Therefore, F5 and F7 in the main file worked.
However, F5 or F7 in a subfile did not work. The main file was like:
...
\input standard_settings.tex
...
\subfile{subfilename.tex} 

with numerous complicating settings in file standard_settings.tex.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

But maybe this is just a second try for the closed TeXstudio: I want to compile the whole file when hitting F5 in a subfile. Hard to say without more information.

Sorry. I had clicked "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style". The answer lies below. Would it have been better to include the answer in the above question part and not in the answer part of the form? I wanted to help those with the same problem and the same Google search as in my title quote.

I now included the answer in the question. I hope that those Googling for "Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}" now more easily see if this hit is what they are looking for.

Sorry, but this is still not really helpful for a Q&A site. The question should always contain all information that is needed to (easily) reproduce the problem. And it should only contain the description of the problem, but not a description of the solution. So as Teempeemm already commented to your answer, the question should be something like: ”I have these files. If I now do …, I get the following error message in log file …”. If you like to answer your own question, you can than show, what changes are needed to the files from the question or what you are doing with them.

Isn't the point of this site that those who Google for their problems (in the web or within SE.com) find the correct answer? (Not to serve SE users nice problems to solve.)
Restricting the question to my special case would make it much slower for a reader to find if this hit is what they were looking for; i.e., counter-productive. The solution is not restricted to my special case.
Else, Googling for "Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}"  finds just 1 hit, a German text with wrong answer. Therefore, I think that the general case must be treated first, before my special case.

No. The purpose of this site is not to be a source for the business model of Google or AI manufacturers, but to make problems and their solutions comprehensible to users. The strict separation of question and answer is one of the fundamental concepts. If you want an abstract problem and its solution in one post, you are better off in a blog.

In contrast to cabohah, I would say that being easily found by search engines is a good goal.  The problem is that this question won't be easily found, and if it is found it would be hard for a searcher to know they've found their answer because your question is so vague.  The ideal is that anyone can read your question and immediately reproduce the problem.  Instead of several paragraphs explaining "I had this text in this file", just post "file 1 had this content:".  You're close after your latest edit, but not quite there.

@Teepeemm Easy finding would not help, if easy understanding and at least easy reproducing is not given. And that's the main point why I think, that the question is currently not helpful and should be improved before re-opening it. So IMHO still making problems and their solutions comprehensible for users is the first goal. Easy finding with search engines is the candy. And if both is not give … :(

I have opened an issue in the github repo of the subfiles package, see github.com/gsalzer/subfiles/issues/36. There, you also find a minimal example reproducing the problem. Feel free to copy it to your question. Please let me know if you think that your problem is misrepresented at github.

The error often appears because \begin{document} is missing in the main file (but appears in the subfile, as required by the package subfiles).
In the "special case", \begin{document} does not appear explicitly in the main file (although implicitly, through \input standard_settings.tex,
but that was not enough for F5 or F7 to work in the subfile in a special case).
That special case can be solved as follows:
I had to insert \begin{document} to the main file to solve this. That is, to split standard_settings.tex into two parts (its contents before and after \begin{document}) and to replace \input standard_settings.tex with the following in the main file:
\input standard_settings1.tex
\begin{document}
\input standard_settings2.tex

Note: this is not an inherent feature of the package subfiles. Also other factors are required (without them, \begin{document} can be in an inputted file), but I was not able to identify the other factors, so I had to use this solution.
Thus, even though it is often said that \input file2.tex works as if file2.tex was copy-pasted in the inputting file, that is not always the case from the \subfile{} point of view.
Also, remember to check that you have the line % !TeX root = ./mainfilename.tex as the first line in  subfilename.tex.
However, if the omission of the above comment line is your only problem, then F7 should work and the F5 error message should be mainfilename.tex error <linenumber> Missing \begin{document}. A or the like, with A being the letter/command that makes LaTeX assume a \begin{document} should have been there first. Even in this case, above that error message, there may be another error message that disappears when you fix this issue.
Note also: all definitions (in the main file) needed in the subfile must be before the line \begin{document} in the main file. (However, those from some \input setting_file1.tex are OK here if that \input setting_file1.tex is before the explicit line \begin{document}.)
I apologize for not producing a full example. I was not able to identify the other necessary factors from my 2.5 MB .tex files and hence had to use the above solution.

Nice answer, but almost useless, because nobody can know this or reproduce from the question. Only you know the contents of your files.

It took me very long to solve this. Searching with the quote in the title did not help. Therefore, I wanted to help those who search with the same quote. (I guess that this only helps some of them, but even so, this could save them lots of work.)

The problem (as you've found) is that the error message is not very descriptive of the actual problem, but that's all you've given in your question.  This would be a better question if you moved some of the setup you've described in your answer into your question: "I have these two files with this content, but it's not working".  Then your Q&A would be more helpful to others.  On the other hand, once you've done that, you might find another question on this site that does answer the question.
